Trying to install Ubuntu with damaged built-in Intel integrated graphics and another external graphics card is good
I have two VGAs, one built-in on the motherboard Intel graphics (damaged) and an external Nvidia GeForce GT 720m graphics card. The Intel integrated graphics is damaged and the other is OK. When I try to install Ubuntu or CentOS the screen turns off every 30 seconds, and to open the screen again I have to press on the power button. How to install Ubuntu and fix this problem?
The problem isn't with the cable I'm sure, but the built-in Intel integrated graphics is damaged, and I want to replace it with the external Nvidia GeForce GY 720m graphics card.

Only Ubuntu products are on-topic here, so if you wish to ask about CentOS you should ask your question on SE Unix & Linux where both Ubuntu & CentOS are on-topic. You provided no Ubuntu product & release details, so we can't provide specific help with Ubuntu (Ubuntu has many installers; you select which you use at download time by ISO & you've not said what you're installing). Your issue description (whilst vague) may also be cable related but you're very light on details.

ok, the release (iso file ) is ubuntu-24.10-desktop-amd64 that i'm trying to install now i'm facing problem that my screen turn of every few seconds during the installation and after that i tried to update the second driver (nvidia) and still the screen turning off

the problem isn't with the cable i'm sure but the build in graphical card is damaged and i want to replace it with the external card NVidia GeForce gt 720m !
